# Add thousand separator to levels in cut function

Tags: r, ggplot2

My x axis labels look like [100000,250000] which makes it hard to understand the numer at first sight, I want it to look like [100.000,250.000], I know that the cut2 function has a formatfun parameter but I think I don´t know how to use it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "formatC" function on your cut data. e.g.

```
formatC(my_cuts, big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ",")
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's create an example to work on:

```
x <- cut(seq(0,1,length.out=8) + 1e6, 3)
```

This is a *factor*.  Although at bottom it's a numeric array, you don't want to format its *values;* you want to format its *levels,* which are the strings associated with its values.  This is what the levels look like in the example (calling `head` to prevent lots of printing in case `x` has many distinct levels):

```
(head(levels(x)))
```

> ```
> [1] "(1000000,1000000.3]"   "(1000000.3,1000000.7]" "(1000000.7,1000001]"
> ```

To format the levels, we need to pick them apart into their numeric components (which are separated by a comma ","), format each component, and reassemble the results.

Here's the picking-apart-and-formatting step in one go, using only base `R` functionality.  It calls `gsub` and `strsplit` on the first line (for cleaning out the "(" and "]" characters and splitting each pair of numeric strings into two strings) and employs `prettyNum` on the second line (for the formatting), which conveniently will format any character string that looks like a number:

```
s <- lapply(strsplit(gsub("]|[(]", "", levels(x)), ","),  
            prettyNum, big.mark=".", decimal.mark=",", input.d.mark=".", preserve.width="individual")
```

(You might not need the `input.d.mark` argument, but I did because my locale uses "." for a decimal point, as you could see above.  The docs say "individual" is the default for setting the output width, but that just isn't the case on my system: I had to specify it explicitly.)

The `paste*` functions will perform the reassembly, whose results we simply re-assign to the levels of `x`:

```
levels(x) <- paste0("(", sapply(s, function(a) paste0(a, collapse="; ")), "]")
```

(Since each number potentially already includes "," and "." delimiters, I have specified a third punctuation mark, ";", to separate the numbers themselves -- but you may use what you wish, of course.)

Let's display the new levels to verify the results:

```
(head(levels(x)))
```

> ```
> [1] "(1.000.000; 1.000.000,3]"   "(1.000.000,3; 1.000.000,7]" "(1.000.000,7; 1.000.001]"
> ```